# No address associated with hostname, errno = 7

Tags: android, flutter, server, runtime-error

I want to receive information from the server.
But it gives me this error:

[image: error]

My code:

[image: my code]

During my research, other people had this problem, which was solved this way, but it didn't work for me:

[image: Add internet access to manifest]

Footnote: I am sure that the link is correct!